# Dispose method c# classes, common note "not be freed until the garbage collector"

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, dispose, idisposable

In some disposable classes for c# there is documentation note:

> Always call Dispose before you release your last reference to the XXXX. Otherwise, the resources it is using will not be freed until the garbage collector calls the XXXX object's Finalize method.

Where XXXX is for instance the [SemaphoreSlim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim.dispose?view=net-5.0#System_Threading_SemaphoreSlim_Dispose) or the [ManualResetEventSlim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.manualreseteventslim.dispose?view=net-5.0#System_Threading_ManualResetEventSlim_Dispose). What I understand from this Note is that if you do not call dispose (*Otherwise*) the resources XXXX is using (*including unmanaged objects*) will be freed eventually by the GC.

**Is my understanding correct?** Because if it is it implies that at least for these classes, there is no real need to actually call the Dispose() on them.

Comment: Consider a `FileStream` object, which has a `Dispose()` method. If you don't dispose the `FileStream` object, it will remain open and likely unflushed until it is garbage collected. That means that any other code that tries to open the file in the meantime is likely to fail. This is a very bad thing. Thus, you should always dispose disposable objects as soon as possible, unless the documentation explicitly says you don't need to for that type. Also, if you don't dispose a disposable, the GC has all the overhead of managing the call to its Finalizer.

Comment: Right, but if I happen to know that I won't use the FileStream again, is this going to be a memory leak or is the GC eventually dispose of all its resources including unmanaged objects?

Comment: It won't cause a memory leak, but I would consider it to be a bug (for the FileStream example).